# Tighter upper bound of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\tanh'(\cosh k)}{\cosh(\sin k)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, convergence-divergence, summation

How do I find tight upper bounds of $$S=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\tanh'(\cosh k)}{\cosh(\sin k)}$$ ? The derivative of $\tanh$ is $\text{sech}^2$, so using $$S=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\cosh^2(\cosh k)\cosh(\sin k)}$$we get that the summand is less than $\frac1{k^2}$ so we have $$0<S<\frac{\pi^2}6$$But the upper bound is too big since Desmos states that $S\approx0.122980505644$. How can we make tighter upper bounds? As a note, this sum is already accurate to at least $12$ digits when the upper bound of the sum is $4$.

Edit: I made a tighter bound by comparing this with $\zeta(8)$. So we have $$0<S<\frac{\pi^8}{9450}$$This is still not a tight bound since it is greater than $1$.

Context: I had something similar to this in a dream.

Comment: What is $\tanh'$? The derivative of $\tanh$?

Comment: @pancini I don’t see what else it could be

Comment: @pancini yes, it is the derivative.

Comment: The numerator is larger than $\frac 14 e^{e^k}$, so that the series converges very quickly.

Comment: @MartinR meant the denominator. But I think that with a bit of thought, the OP should have found that.

Comment: I have the feeling that there is something not correct. For me, the summand is $$\sinh (k) \text{sech}^2(\cosh (k)) \text{sech}(\sin (k))$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici $\tanh'\circ\cosh\ne(\tanh\circ\cosh)'.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The denominators in $$a_n = \frac{1}{\cosh^2(\cosh k)\cosh(\sin k)}$$ grow extremely fast, so that only few terms are necessary in order to compute $S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ to a high precision.

Using $\cosh(\sin k) \ge 1$ and $\cosh k \ge \frac 12 e^k$ we get the estimate
$$
 \frac{1}{a_k} \ge \left(\frac 12 e^{\frac 12 e^k} \right)^2 = \frac 14 e^{e^k} \, .
$$
It follows that
$$
 a_{n+k} \le  4 e^{-e^{n+k}} = 4 e^{-e^{n}e^{k}} \le 4 \left( e^{-e^n}\right)^k
$$
so that the series remainders can be estimated by
$$
 R_n = \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty a_n = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{n+k} \le 4 \frac{e^{-e^n}}{1-e^{-e^n}} = \frac{4}{e^{e^n}-1} \,.
$$
So
$$
 R_3 \le \frac{4}{e^{e^3}-1} \approx 7.549 10^{-9} < 10^{-8} \\
 R_4 \le \frac{4}{e^{e^4}-1} \approx 7.769 10^{-24} < 10^{-23} \\
$$
which shows that $a_1+a_2+a_3$ is accurate to at least 8 decimal digits, and $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4$ is accurate to at least 23 decimal digits. In particular,
$$
 S \le a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + \frac{4}{e^{e^3}-1} \approx 0.122980513 \, .
$$